# How do you pronounce and hand-write the symbol §?

Tags: legal-writing

How do you pronounce and write by hand the symbol §, which is used extensively in legal writing?

And what do you call the symbol?  For example, "#" is called the *number symbol* or *hash*.  "&" is called "ampersand."  Should I call it "the section symbol"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a question about typefaces, not the law.

Comment: He's asking how to say it. That is commonly used in legal cites here in the US.

Comment: @Putvi - Could be he, could be she, could be they.  In my case, I go by "they."

Comment: One of the purposes of this site is for questions about "Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory" I think this is, in effect a question about a legal term, and about the process of reading adn writing legal citations, aand so is on-topic here.

Comment: Is there a reason it would have to be written by hand? It is rarely used in non-type written documents. Indeed, even in documents that are typewritten, the section sign is often omitted, and in non-type written documents it would be more common to spell out "section" than than use the symbol.

Comment: "#" is also called a "pound symbol"

Answer (score 6):

It stands for section. As in "section 8 article b" or whatever.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you help me with the other part, how do you write this symbol by hand?

Comment: It is probably hard to write by hand unless you have good art skills, I guess. I would just try to write an S on top of an S. I'm sure it's not going to be as good as typing it, if you write it by hand.

Comment: Based on @Putvi 's comment, I tried to draw one by hand just that way- S on top of S. I have terrible handwriting, no visual art skills, and I am not a lawyer or in that field (so I have never had occasion to try to write one). It came out recognizable. Start the lower S in the middle- maybe upper third- of the first diagonal S.

Comment: I normally write it "s."

Answer (score 3):

It's pronounced "section" and usually referred to as "the section sign."

I've also seen it called a "silcrow," which is a neologism derived from its similarities to [the pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow), and which I prefer myself.

Comment: "silcrow" seems to be asking for misunderstanding by the hard of hearing (who frequently have trouble distinguishing the sound of one consonant from another, if they can hear consonants at all).

Comment: Why do you like the pilcrow better than the section sign?  the section sign looks so graceful.

Comment: Agreed -- I just prefer calling § a "silcrow" to calling it "section sign."

Answer (score 2):

As far as the name of the symbol goes, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) uses **section sign** for its article on the symbol, and also notes that the terms **section mark**, **section symbol**, **silcrow**, **double-S**, and **paragraph mark** can be used.  Note, however, that the last two could be taken to mean other symbols (ß and ¶, respectively) depending on the context;  the first three are (IMHO) less ambiguous.

As far as how to handwrite it, I usually do it by handwriting two capital S's, vertically displaced from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Besides "section" in the common law, it can have different meanings in other legal systems.

For example, in Germany, § marks a "Paragraf".

Answer (score 1):

§ stands for 'section'. You can type it on your QWERTY keyboard by holding down the 'Alt' key and typing '21'.

Comment: Interesting, I'd always used the alt code of Alt+0167 for that symbol. I wonder why there would be 2 codes fort hat.

Comment: Seems like many letters/symbols have 2 or more codes. Ex. For ñ you can type ALT 164  or 241, for ¥ there is ALT 157 or 0165, so I wonder too why the redundancy.

Comment: A in ASCII is 41 hex/65 decimal, as well as unicode Alt+0041, but in html &#65 as well as &#x41. Often one of the codes is the other in decimal.

Comment: Alt 21 is a very Windows PC specific action. See [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign#Keyboard_entry) various ways of typing it.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The difference between the two codes relates to what [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) you are using to render the § glyph.